# Windows or Linux x86 Scheduler instructions

Tags: kernel-mode, kernel

I want to understand how multi process scheduler works on x86 CPU with Linux or Windows kernels.

I have read there is a kind of "timer" inside CPU. This timer gives "time slices" to each process.

What i want to understand is what really happens when a time slice is finished. Does an interrupt fire ? or something else ? I suppose kernel code is runned between 2 slices but how...

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the interrupt happens and the process context is saved, the next process' context is loaded and that second process is run. See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55796/how-does-the-os-scheduler-give-take-control-of-hw).

Comment: @bart1e it's on a thread level, not process

Comment: @macro_controller: Do you mean this is not the same thing for process and threads ?

Comment: @Bob5421I mean that the actual entities that are being scheduled are threads, not processes